# Using a variable in a mysql query, in a C++ MFC program

Tags: c++, mysql, mfc

After extensive trawling of the internet, I still haven't found any solution for this problem.

I'm writing a small C++ app that connects to an online database and outputs the data in a listbox.

I need to enable a search function using an edit box, but I can't get the query to work while using a variable.

My code is:

```
res = mysql_perform_query (conn, "select distinct artist from Artists");
//res = mysql_perform_query (conn, "select album from Artists where artist = ' ' ");



while((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) != NULL){
    CString str;
    UpdateData();

    str = ("%s\n", row[0]);

    UpdateData(FALSE);
    m_list_control.AddString(str);

}
```

The first "`res =`" line is working fine, but I need the second one to work. I have a member variable `m_search_edit` set up for the edit box, but any way that I try to include it in the sql statement causes errors.

eg.

```
res = mysql_perform_query (conn, "select album from Artists where artist = '"+m_search_edit+" ' ");
```

causes this error:

> error C2664: 'mysql_perform_query' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'class CString' to 'char *'
>   No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called"

And when I convert `m_search_edit` to a `char*` it gives me a " Cannot add 2 pointers" error.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: Aren't you missing an `sprintf` in the line `str = ...;`?

Comment: By the way, you're setting yourself up for SQL injection. Maybe not a huge deal for desktop applications, but you should encode `m_search_edit` properly nonetheless.

Comment: No, sprintf was not working and when I removed it the program worked.
Sorry I should have been more clear this is a MFC APP.

Comment: On the  SQL injection problem, its just a small project for college, so i`m not too worried about that aspect at the minute, just trying to get the program working first. Thanks for the help though, I wouldnt have had any idea what SQL injection was without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you are probably building for Unicode, which means that CString consists of wide characters.  You can't directly concatenate an ASCII string with a wide character string (and you can't concatenate string literals with the + operator either).

I think the clearest way to build the query string here is by using the `CT2CA` macro to convert the contents of the edit control from Unicode to ASCII and `CStringA::Format` to insert them in the string

```
CStringA query;
query.Format("select album from Artists where artist = '%s'", CT2CA(m_search_edit));
res = mysql_perform_query(conn, query);
```

And as Thomas pointed out, you should be aware that this leaves the door open for SQL injection...

EDIT: I'm not sure where this `mysql_perform_query` API comes from, but from the error message you posted it looks like it also requires a writable buffer (`char *` instead of `const char *`).  Since I can't find documentation for it, I don't know how big it expects that buffer to be, but to get a modifiable buffer out of a CString, look into the [GetBuffer()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa314880%28VS.60%29.aspx) and [ReleaseBuffer()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300574%28v=VS.60%29.aspx) methods:

```
CStringA query;
query.Format(...); // Replace ... with parameters from above
char * buffer = query.GetBuffer(MAX_STRING_LENGTH); // make length big enough for mysql
res = mysql_perform_query(conn, buffer)
query.ReleaseBuffer();
```

EDIT2 (in response to latest comment):

Thank you for providing the definition of your `mysql_perform_query` function.  When asking questions in the future, keep in mind it's helpful to know when you've created helper functions like this one.

In this case, your `mysql_perform_query` function never modifies the query string -- the only thing it does is pass it to `mysql_query`, which takes a `const char *`, so there's no reason you shouldn't declare its parameter `const` too.  Once you do that, you'll find my first answer works (no need for GetBuffer/ReleaseBuffer):

```
MYSQL_RES *mysql_perform_query(MYSQL *conn, const char * query)
{
   // Body as written in comment.
}
```

Comment: This doesnt work either. Its giving 5 errors with the "A" left in after "Cstring" and 2 errors if I remove the "A".
The two errors are CT2CA: Undeclared Identifier and
'mysql_perform_query' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'class CString' to 'char *'
I should have pointed out in the first post that i`m doing this on VC++ 6.

Comment: I tried rebuilding the program in Visual Studio 2008. 
I got this error from your piece of code:
    Error 1 error C2664: 'mysql_perform_query' :        cannot convert parameter 2 from 'CStringA' to 'char *'

Comment: @D.Gaughan what mysql API is this?  I couldn't find documentation  for `mysql_perform_query` on the web, only `mysql_query`.  Anyway, CString only has an implicit conversion to `const char *`.  If you need to get a modifiable buffer for a function that takes a non-`const`, you should look into GetBuffer() and ReleaseBuffer().  I'm editing my answer.

Comment: I`m using the mysql C++ connector.

I have this block of code at the start of the program, I don`t know if this is of any use to you though.

    MYSQL_RES* mysql_perform_query(MYSQL *conn, char *sql_query)
    {
   // send the query to the database
   if (mysql_query(conn, sql_query))
   {
     // printf("MySQL query error : %s\n", mysql_error(conn));
     // exit(1);
   }
 
   return mysql_use_result(conn);
    }


The code you posted is still giving errors. 
The main one is that  

query.Buffer(...): no overloaded function contains 0 parameters.

Comment: @D.Gaughan you say `query.Buffer(...)` gives errors, but that didn't appear in my post.  Make sure you get the whole name, `*Get*Buffer` or `*Release*Buffer`, or if you're calling `query.Format`, that you replace the `...` with the parameters from the first example (I just cut them out of the second example to keep the focus on the usage of GetBuffer and ReleaseBuffer).

Comment: I`ve tried the new method and unfortunatley its still not working. Its compiling without errors, but i`m still not getting any output from the program.

Comment: @D.Gaughan if your compilation issues are solved, then I would recommend opening a new question about why you're not getting output.

Comment: Ok i`ll do that now. Thank you for your help.